# Aggregating data sets in PHP for maximum performance

Tags: php, multithreading, node.js, search

We have a high transaction PHP site which performs well overall, however the weak link is slow search results.  The reason being we aggregate data from numerous sources.  For example:

User hits search > Get Result 1 from native database > Get Result 2 from API 2 > Get Result 3 from API 3 > Get Result 4 from API 4 > Aggregate and sort > Output to browser.

Data comes from various sources, some is from our own PostgreSQL db, but the rest is from various external APIs.

As you can see, this sequential access is a real killer.  I have been investigating various approaches to using threads so I can assign each request to it's own thread and perform a final aggregation.

So far I'm leaning towards writing a Java based layer specifically for searching.  The idea being I send one message to the Java service, and it handles the tread pool and aggregation.  I was thinking of using node.js, but I think it may be difficult to achieve the end result.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?  I am open to using any language or technology.

Comment: No need for java: http://php.net/Thread !!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your request execution time can't be smaller then minimal API request execution time even if you make all sub-requests running concurrently in async mode. It is true if you need apply aggregation function to all API and  DB data. But if you not need it, try to separate request to small parts. You also can try to use tasks queue like Gearman.

**EDITED** You also can consider any kind of **asynchronous** calls here. Try start tasks in Gearman *asynchronously* for each api calls, then fetch data from you db in main request process and begin checks async tasks execution result (you can share it in memcache or redis i.e.). Such you parallelize a part of aggregation work.

Answer (score 0):

this is just an alternative option that hasn't been mentioned yet.

you could stick to pure php - just write 4 new processes that run as daemons listening for local socket connections. your search script can make a socket connection to each daemon and send the search params to them, and then just wait for the results. you could efficiently wait for results on the sockets using `select()`, but even the naive solution of just using blocking `fgets()` calls in sequence on all 4 sockets will give you good concurrency so long as you send the messages to all 4 daemons before trying to read the results from any.

but, this doesnt automatically provide good concurrency when say, 10 different users perform searches at the same time. the daemons might be able to effectively service multiple socket connections at once. for the native db query, your driver will need to support asynchronous queries. and those apis calls are probably using sockets/http. sockets /http requests are easy to parallelize by using `select()`, or maybe consider `curl_multi`.

but...using nice language supported threads might be simpler at the end of the day.